# How do I install Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, docker

I would like to build and run Docker containers on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. How do I install Docker?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Docker comes in two flavours: The Comunity Edition (CE) and the Enterprise Edition (EE). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45018786/562769) for the differences. Just take Docker CE if you don't know which to take.

There are two ways of installing it (thank you, [Katu](https://askubuntu.com/users/188999/katu) and [Suor](https://askubuntu.com/users/28161/suor)!). The official docker way is a bit more recent.

### (A) Official Ubuntu Repositories

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

In the past this way was discouraged as the docker package was super outdated. The [universe sources](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/docker.io) are fairly recent now.

### (B) Official Docker Way

The [Ubuntu installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) list all you need in detail, but in most cases it boils down to:

(1) Set up the docker repository

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

(2) Install Docker CE

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

(3) Verify the installation

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

The latest version can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). It was 18.06 in November 2018. This version is available in the sources from above, whereas the default Ubuntu package sources only contain Docker 1.5 ([source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/docker)). You can find changes in the [docker release notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/). Version 1.5 is so old that I could not find out how old it is.

Comment: How is this better than Ubuntu repo version?

Comment: The official Docker sources are way more recent. See my updated comment.

Comment: @MartinThoma in my Ubuntu 16.04 the docker.io package is version 17.03.2 (November 2018)

Comment: @Katu Are you sure you use the default package sources? https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/docker.io says docker.io is in version 1.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). edit: Ah, in [universe sources](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/docker.io) there is a newer version!

Comment: Thank you, @Katu and Suor! I've adjusted my answer

Answer (score 29):

To install the Ubuntu repository version

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Check the version with

```
docker --version
```

You may still want to do the [post-install steps](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/). Thanks @wisbucky

Comment: This works fine in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as well

Comment: This is now the best way nowadays, since the Ubuntu repos are keeping up with the docker releases. Currently, the Ubuntu `docker.io` package is at `docker 18.06.1`. Ubuntu [`docker.io` package was updated on Sep 27, 2018](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/d/docker.io/docker.io_18.06.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1/changelog), which is only a month after that [version was released on Aug 21, 2018](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v18.06.1-ce). You may still want to do the post-install steps: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/ .

Comment: I wonder who thought it would be a good idea to have all these indistinguishable package names available at the same time: `docker`, `docker-ce`, `docker-engine` and of course `docker.io`...

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way to install docker on Ubuntu using following command that you can get from the https://get.docker.com/

This script is meant for quick & easy install via:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

or

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

For test builds (ie. release candidates):

```
$ curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com | sh
```

or

```
 wget -qO- https://test.docker.com/ | sh
```

For rc build with experimental feature:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://experimental.docker.com | sh
```

or

```
 wget -qO- https://experimental.docker.com/ | sh
```

Comment: piping directly into a shell is bad advice, no matter how commonplace it is.

Comment: Really ? In typical situation you cant see source code at all, you just trust source of binary file (downloaded and executed)

Answer (score 2):

To install the community edition, add the GPG key

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the docker repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

sudo apt-get update
```

To make sure, you're going to install docker from Docker repo,

```
apt-cache policy docker-ce
```

Now install docker,

```
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

It would be running by default, but you can check the status

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

Answer (score 2):

BTW, for **Linux Mint** *(which is based on ubuntu)*, need to change the release name by hand, after adding the repository.

**Sub steps:**

- `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`
- According to underling ubuntu versions:

  - Ubuntu 16.04
    Change `sarah` or other name, to `xenial`.
  - Ubuntu 18.04
    Change `tara` or other name, to `bionic`.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps to install docker-ce in Ubuntu -

1. install the dependencies first

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
   ```
2. add the GPG key for the official Docker repository to the system:

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Add the Docker repository in sources.list.d to APT sources using below command -

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable edge"
   ```
4. verify if you are able to install Docker from Docker repository

   ```
   apt-cache policy docker-ce
   ```
5. Finally, install Docker CE package with below command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
   ```

Voila, you have installed Docker-CE. You can verify installation by checking the version of *docker-ce* installed

```
docker --version
```

For more detailed instructions, follow [this tutorial](https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/06/25/how-to-install-docker-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 1):

Debian installation.

1. check your ubuntu code name

`lsb_release -a | grep Code`

> Codename: xenial

1. check your cpu architecture

`lscpu | grep Arch`

> Architecture:x86_64

Finaly download your debian src.
Go to https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/, choose your Ubuntu version, browse to pool/stable/ and choose amd64, armhf, ppc64el, or s390x. Download the .deb file for the Docker version you want to install.

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`

```
docker -v
```

> Docker version 18.06.0-ce