# How can i update my docker version in Linux environment?

Tags: docker, aws

I need to update my docker version as per older version its showing some issue related to go code so, i have to update the docker version as i found the issue.
My linux machine in AWS.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This question on Server Fault https://serverfault.com/questions/682340/update-the-container-of-a-service-in-amazon-ecs might help you, eventually update your question with specific issues you'll find.

Comment: Mr.Shunz , no actually I was asking about the docker one, not the container. but still, thank you for your suggestion and thank you for your welcome words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938700/how-do-i-install-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your docker version using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache madison docker-ce
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION>
sudo service docker restart
```

Note: You have to replace the version in the `<VERSION>` with your preferred version.