# How would I run multiple applications on my Ubuntu Server

Tags: 18.04, server, webserver, webapps, nextcloud

I'd like my server to run ubuntu server OS on the M.2 drive, on that OS I'd like to create a cloud server by running nextCloud on a difference instance and have all the nextCloud data to be stored on a separate hard drive, and then I'd like the sever to also run another instance to use it as a time Machine backup for my mac and store all of its data and backups on another separate hard drive. How would I achieve this?

(I'd also later down the line to be able to add more instances to run some web apps and home automation scripts etc.)

Comment: [LXD](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxd.html) and [Docker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938700) are common container systems used in Ubuntu. Both are reasonably easy to learn.

Comment: @user535733 would each container have it's own security and rules set like its own firewall and ip address or would everything just come through one firewall and ip address?

Comment: If you wish, yes. If not, then no.

Comment: @user535733 okay, thanks for the information

Comment: What do you mean by "instance"? Do you want to have containerized or virtualized environments or just install everything directly on the host OS? In the latter case just install all the apps you need and configure them to write to the location you want to. Also on Linux you can mount disks into whatever directory you need.

Comment: @StefanHorning well that's the thing, I don't know which one suits me best. I'd like to have like half of my server dedicated to my personal cloud and my timemachine backups and the other half for a project that will be hosted on the outside internet. So I was thinking of two virtual machines, one for my personal stuff and the other for my project and web apps that will be accessible from the internet?

Comment: I guess it depends how experienced you are with virtualization or containerization. As the networking still has to go through the host OS the security gain of running in container/vm would only be small as you could still mess up networking configs and allow access unintentionally. Personally I would just install everything on OS level and perhaps run different apps as different users, so they can only access their own data. If you are behind a NAT router just the forwarded ports will be reachable from the public internet anyway.

Comment: Also I think your question is more suitable for a discussion thread in some Linux/Server forum instead of simple QA platform like StackExchange.